# Passing Access Token from an api to different pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, spotify, spotify-app

So I'm currently using the Spotify API with reactJS and get the access token of a user when the login is authenticated by Spotify, it redirects to the first page that I set it to, ('/') of Component={Home}. But from that Home page, I want to route to a different page with the path '/playlist' onClick of a button in which I push the url by,

```
this.props.history.push('/playlist/#access_tokens=' + spotifyApi.getAccessTokens())
```

This is the only way I got it to be with the access token passing in the URL.

Is this bad practice?

Comment: Context would be a simpler way to pass the access token around: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen But even with a Context, won't I still have to push the path name the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to understand your goals for me, but if you want to pass access_token only by url, you can use state to hide token from the user

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/playlist',
  state: {
    accessTokens: spotifyApi.getAccessTokens()
  }
})
```

and then get it by the next way

```
const location = useLocation();
const tokens = location.state && location.state.accessTokens;
```

But i can't understand why do not you pass your token to any management library like redux, mobx or some other browser storage (localStorage, sessionStorage)?

Comment: I dont use any management library because what I'm trying to create is a relatively simple application, only 3 total pages, a login page (spotify oauth) -> a user input page -> page that returns something (music playlist) based on that input.

Comment: And thanks btw, I forgot that I could just pass it in the state.

Comment: @surpol in this case i recommend you to pass token to localStorage and it will be available on all pages and available after page refreshing ^^, as in the router state, but router state will be undefined if you copy url address and open it in new tab

Comment: late response but, yeah i've been using localstorage to store the access and refresh tokens. Is that bad practice though?